# Wix "Product element contains an unexpected child element util: RegistrySearch" error message on launch condition

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

I am totally new to Wix and I have been tasked with this.

The installer should prompt the message "Application requires Reportviewer". It should check if reportViewer is installed and if not throw the message at the beginning of installation itself.

This is what I am trying to do (randomly trying things out as I still do not understand the details)

```
<Condition Message="This application requires ReportViewer.">
  <![CDATA[ReportViewerV10 OR ReportViewerWow64V10]]>
</Condition>

<util:RegistrySearch
 Root="HKLM"
 Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ReportViewer\v10.0"
 Value="Install"
 Variable="ReportViewerV10"
 Win64="yes"
  />
<util:RegistrySearch
Root="HKLM"
Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ReportViewer\v10.0"
Value="Install"
Variable="ReportViewerWow64V10"
Win64="yes"
  />
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a reference to http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension in your main container tag in WIX project to refer util:RegistrySearch.

**Document Should Look Like**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Include xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2003/01/wi">
.
.
.
</Include>
```

**OR**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2003/01/wi">
.
.
.
</Wix>
```

You can keep this utility call in a `Bundle` tag or a `Fragment` tag only.

Refer [RegistrySearch Element (Util Extension) Documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_registrysearch.htm) for more details on this.
Refer [WIX Documenation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/main.htm) for more ideas.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much. If I have two conditions, say XP SP3 should be present and then the ReportViewer check, How do I make sure Xp SP3 gets checked first before ReportViewer check?

Comment: I am not so sure about it but I think the order in which the conditions are put up in the source it will give priority.